# Dependencies missing in current linux-64 channels when trying to install tensorflow-gpu with conda command

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I tried conda install tensorflow-gpu in my terminal and I get this

```
Error:  Dependencies missing in current linux-64 channels: 
 - tensorflow -> numpy >=1.11 -> blas * mkl
- tensorflow -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * openblas
 - tensorflow -> tensorflow-tensorboard -> numpy >=1.11 -> blas * 
openblas
 - tensorflow -> numpy 1.12* -> blas * openblas
 - tensorflow -> tensorflow-base ==1.3.0 -> numpy >=1.11 -> blas * mkl
- tensorflow -> tensorflow-base ==1.3.0 -> numpy >=1.11 -> blas * openblas
   - tensorflow -> tensorflow-tensorboard -> numpy >=1.11 -> blas * mkl
 - tensorflow -> numpy 1.12* -> blas * mkl
 - tensorflow -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - tensorflow -> numpy >=1.11 -> blas * openblas
```

I also installed openblas after but still same error. What is the issue?

Comment: I hope this should help ```conda update conda```

Comment: @pic0 any other solution? I am not sudo to do that!

Comment: Install this lib to docker container;?

Comment: I know this is ancient, but I have the same issue, and the answer doesn't work for me under the problem that "PackageNotFound: conda".  Do you remeber by any chance how you fixed this?

Answer (score 13):

As @pic0 has suggested, after doing

`conda update conda`

I were able to install all needed packages.

If you have installed Anaconda on the default folder (for me is `/home/user/anaconda`), you should not need to use `sudo`.